# JSON.net VB.net parse to get only colors from json return

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Hey all I am trying to parse the following JSON in order to get the colors for the exterior:

```
{ 
    "styles": [{ 
        "make": { 
            "id": 200001444,
            .....etc etc
        }, 
        "model": { 
            "id": "Honda_Pilot", 
            .....etc etc
        }, 
        "engine": { 
            "id": "200058127", 
            .....etc etc
            "rpm": { 
                "horsepower": 5700, 
                "torque": 4800 
            }, 
            "valve": { 
                "timing": "variable valve timing", 
                "gear": "single overhead camshaft" 
            } 
        }, 
        "transmission": { 
            "id": "200058128", 
            .....etc etc
        }, 
        "drivenWheels": "four wheel drive", 
        .....etc etc
        "colors": [{ 
            "category": "Interior", 
            "options": [{ 
                "id": "200058068", 
                "name": "Blue", 
                .....etc etc                    
            }] 
        }, { 
            "category": "Exterior", 
            "options": [{ 
                "id": "200058073", 
                "name": "Crystal Black Pearl",  
                .....etc etc                   
                } 
            }, { 
                "id": "200058072", 
                "name": "Polished Metal Metallic", 
                .....etc etc
```

So far I have gotten to the "colors" but I am unable to get any further:

VB.net code:

```
Dim json2

    Using httpClient = New HttpClient()
       json2 = Await httpClient.GetStringAsync("URL HERE")
    End Using

    Dim rootObject2 = JObject.Parse(json2)

    For Each token As JToken In rootObject2("styles")
       Dim results As List(Of JToken) = token.Children().ToList

       For Each item As JProperty In results
           Select Case item.Name
              Case "colors"
                For Each subitem As JObject In item.Values
                    Dim tmp = subitem("category")

                    For Each subitem2 As JObject In tmp.Values
                        Dim tmp2 = subitem("category")
                    Next
                Next
           End Select
       Next
    Next
```

I am sure there's a simpler way of going about this but I just wanted to show that I did try to figure it out before coming here to get help on the code.

I am trying to loop through and get **all Exterior colors** *by name*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
    For Each style As JToken In rootObject2("styles")
        Dim model As String = style.SelectToken("model.id").ToString()
        Console.WriteLine("Exterior colors for " & model & ":")
        For Each colorCategory As JToken In style("colors")
            Dim categoryName As String = colorCategory("category").ToString()
            If categoryName = "Exterior" Then
                For Each opt As JToken In colorCategory("options")
                    Dim color as String = opt("name").ToString()
                    Console.WriteLine("  " & color)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IVc2EC

Comment: That did it! Thanks, Brian!

Comment: No problem; glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JsonSerializer` class instance.

In a **Console (Module) Application**, ensure you include `System.Web.Extensions` as a reference to your project...

Define your Models that will be used in the **Deserilization** process.

#### **VB.NET**

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim result = GetData()
    End Sub

    Public Class MakeStyle
        Public Property Id As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class ModelStyle
        Public Property Id As String
    End Class

    Public Class EngineStyle
        Public Property Id As String
        Public Property RotationsPerMinute As EngineRotationsPerMinuteStyle
    End Class

    Public Class EngineRotationsPerMinuteStyle
        Public Property HorsePower As Integer
        Public Property Torque As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Payload
        Public Property Make As MakeStyle
        Public Property Model As ModelStyle
        Public Property Engine As EngineStyle
        Public Property Colors As IEnumerable(Of ColorStyle)
    End Class

    Public Class ColorStyleOptionItem
        Public Property Id As String
        Public Property Name As String
    End Class

    Public Class ColorStyle
        Public Property Category As String
        Public Property Options As IEnumerable(Of ColorStyleOptionItem)
    End Class

    Public Class DataItem
        Public Property Category As String
        Public Property Id As String
        Public Property Name As String
    End Class


    Public Function GetData() As IEnumerable(Of DataItem)
        Dim payloadString As String = GetDemoData() ' json serialized data

        Dim serializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim payload = serializer.Deserialize(Of Payload)(payloadString) ' sets Property Values of Payload to 'Nothing' when the json fields are not present in the json string.

        Dim data As IEnumerable(Of DataItem) = payload.Colors.SelectMany(Function(item) item.Options.Select(Function(opt) New DataItem With {.Category = item.Category, .Id = opt.Id, .Name = opt.Name}))
        GetData = data
    End Function

    Public Function GetDemoData() As String
        Dim serializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()

        GetDemoData = serializer.Serialize(New Payload() With {
                                       .Make = New MakeStyle() With {.Id = 200001444},
                                       .Model = New ModelStyle() With {.Id = "Honda_Pilot"},
                                       .Engine = New EngineStyle With {.Id = "200058127", .RotationsPerMinute = New EngineRotationsPerMinuteStyle() With {.HorsePower = 5700, .Torque = 4800}},
                                       .Colors = New ColorStyle() {
                                           New ColorStyle() With {
                                               .Category = "Interior",
                                               .Options = New ColorStyleOptionItem() {
                                                   New ColorStyleOptionItem() With {.Id = "200058068", .Name = "Blue"}
                                               }
                                           },
                                           New ColorStyle() With {
                                               .Category = "Exterior",
                                               .Options = New ColorStyleOptionItem() {
                                                   New ColorStyleOptionItem() With {.Id = "200058073", .Name = "Crystal Black Pearl"},
                                                   New ColorStyleOptionItem() With {.Id = "200058072", .Name = "Polished Metal Metallic"}
                                               }
                                           }
                                       }
                                   })

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: I used more explicit class names in **VB.NET** because of the case-insesative nature of the language..

Comment: also, note that `SelectMany` flattens `IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of DataItem))` to just `IEnumerable(Of DataItem)`